# how to add a word two lines above certain word in multiples places

Tags: search, normal-mode, replace

my text look like this in several places of the file:

```
FDE
 PW91k
 XCNADD PBE
 ::FULLGRID
END


END 
eor
```

and I want to introduce a word two lines above "eor" word throughout. I have tried

```
 :,.-2/eor/foo/g
```

and similar expressions, non worked so far.

Can you please help me with a trick that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
:g/^eor/-2normal Ofoo
```

Explanation:

- `:g/^eor/`:  For every line that starts with "eor"
- `-2`:  go two lines up
- `Ofoo`: open a line above and enter "foo"

The `:g` stands for "global". See `:help :g` for details.